# PHP: If empty 2 variables for Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am working in a Drupal template. I want to know if two variables exist, and if they do not then do or show something else. I know how to do this for only one variable, but what is the correct syntax to look for two? My code is below.

```
<?php if (!empty($right) && !empty($left)): ?>
    <div id="content-main">
   <?php endif; ?>
```

I also tried it this way.

```
<?php if (!empty($right)&&($left)): ?>
    <div id="content-main">
   <?php endif; ?>
```

and this way.

```
<?php if (!isset($right)&&($left)): ?>
    <div id="content-main">
   <?php endif; ?>
```

None of them work, how do I fix this?

Comment: `if (isset($right) && isset($left))` otherwise make `var_dump($right,$left);` and check the content of the variables

Comment: I altered it a little. I didn't show 2 other if statements I also need to pass thru. The final code is `<?php if (empty($right) && empty($left)): ?>
    <div id="content-main">
    <?php else: ?>
   <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

empty() doesn't check variable initialization, it only checks if it contains a defined set of values that are considered empty ( "", 0, for example).

Your third example is in the right direction, but needs a small tweak:

```
<?php if (!isset($right)&&!isset($left)): ?>
<div id="content-main">
<?php endif; ?>
```

The second conditional check after && requires its own isset() as well.

hope this helps.